# using @data-bind in ASP.NET MVC htmlAttributes throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and `KnockoutJS`. I was trying to add the binding into my View Helpers like this ...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name", @size = "35", @data-bind = "value: aName" })
```

But this throws the exception ...

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Can anyone enlighten me on what this means - and moreover, how to solve it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't like the hyphen in the property name. To fix this change `@data-bind` to `@data_bind` and this will then render with a hyphen on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC2, you can use the following jquery function to change the data_bind to data-bind:

```
        // MVC2 fix for data_bind
        $('[data_bind]').each(function(i, item) {
            item = $(item);
            item.attr("data-bind",item.attr("data_bind"));
            item.removeAttr("data_bind");
        });
```

Comment: @AndrewBarber:"I am using...". True and fair enough, however it helped me out a lot (we're stuck at MVC 2). It helped me in the way that I now know that it isn't supported version prior to MVC3.